# Is Christ's love for us greater than the Father's?

Tags: nature-of-god, trinity, love

The Father's love for us:

> See what **great** love the Father has lavished on us, that we should be
>   called children of God! And that is what we are! The reason the world
>   does not know us is that it did not know him. (1 John 3:1, NIV)
>
> For God so loved the world that he gave his one and only Son, that
>   whoever believes in him shall not perish but have eternal life. (John
>   3:16, NIV)

The Son's love for us:

> This is how we know what love is: Jesus Christ laid down his life for
>   us. And we ought to lay down our lives for our brothers and sisters.
>   (1 John 3:16, NIV)
>
> **Greater** love has no one than this: to lay down one’s life for one’s
>   friends. (John 15:13, NIV)

Which one is a greater love; to give the one and only son, or to give one's own life?
Is the love of the Father and the Son for us equally same? Who has greater love for us?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is problematic whenever we attempt to separate the inseparable Trinity, so let us acknowledge that to begin with.

The Bible never seems to suggest that the Holy Triune God has the capacity to love in varying measures.  Indeed, God only knows one way to love.  His love is complete and total--not partial.  His love, like He Himself, does not increase or decrease.  His love does not grow, diminish, expand or contract.

Thus, the fact that the Father and the Son (and the Spirit) each love mankind indicates that their love is equivalent and complete.

Answer (score 6):

> I and my Father are one.
>
> John 10:30

Jesus and the Father had the plan of redemption from the beginning of this world. Their plans are the same because they are the same in thought. They love us immensely and equally. Their very essence is love.

> Whoever does not love does not know God, because God is love
>
> 1 John 4:8

If you read through 1 John 4 you will see that love is from God, that is the Godhead. Father, Son, and Holy Spirit. Therefore because of this, the love of Jesus is not greater than that of His Father, or the Holy spirit for that matter.

EDIT: I'll also include this one:

> As the Father has loved me, so have I loved you. Now remain in my
>   love.
>
> John 15:9

Comment: FYI: Edits are committed to the server only after 5 minutes are over from the first activity. Any change within 5 minutes belongs to the same edit history.

Comment: Oh I see. Does this mean that it does not show the edited part, or it just doesn't show it as an edit?

Comment: See for yourself. No edit history is there. But if you do it now, since 5 minutes are over, it will have edit history.